# How to publish your thesis on Google Books?

Tags: google-books

While searching for a certain thesis, I have often found that some of those thesis also show up on Google Books.

Is there a provision where I could publish my thesis online on Google Books?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join the Google partner program and sign up as an author. That should give you the privilege to publish your own work. [More details here](http://books.google.com/intl/en/googlebooks/publisherresources.html).